# How to set pass phrase for yii apns-gcm

Tags: php, yii, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I'm using yii apns-gcm with below settings in console.php config to run as a background process.

My issue is it prompt for PEM pass phrase:
And when I enter the pass phrase it works.

Does anyone know how to set passphrase for this?

Note:

```
Yii::app()->attachEventHandler('onEndRequest', array($this, 'onApplicationEndRequest'));
```

My settings in config

```
'apns' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.apns-gcm.YiiApns',
            'environment' => 'sandbox',
            'pemFile' => 'runtime/apnssert/ck.pem',
            'dryRun' => false, 
            'options' => array(
                'sendRetryTimes' => 5
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: you can add correct path of pemfile refer this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/apns-gcm/

Comment: Actually I added the pem file but this is something else.